# Selenium WebDriver throws WebDriverException while locating any element of Page with AJAX call on MAC Safari

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, safari

I have an issue with Selenium Webdriver on Mac Safari. Selenium throwing WebDriverException on Safari while locating an element on a Page which contains AJAX calls in the code. The problem comes on all Selenium 3+ versions. On Selenium 2.53, it was working fine. 
Is there any other way to locate those elements? Please suggest.

Comment: can you paste your code for reference

Comment: Which type of _WebDriverException _ ? Update the question with your code trial, HTML and error stack trace please.